# OSX C++ Xcode: Pasting long input into console gives upside down question marks

Tags: c++, import, cin, getline

We've made a program that takes a long string of tab-delimited input pasted into the console window and splits it up into the correct variables. However, lately with some long strings of metadata, a bunch of upside down question marks have appeared - sometimes after what has been pasted in, sometimes before, and sometimes both... Here are some screenshots of when we paste in a bunch of filler numbers:
[image: 1000 characters]
[image: Almost 1200 characters]
[image: 1400 characters]

It doesn't appear to be terribly consistent where the upside down question marks appear. We are pasting in normal English metadata, no special characters or other languages.

Here is the code that is getting the information:

```
string FAImport;
cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
cout << "\nPlease copy and paste the information from the finding aid and press Enter: \n";
getline(cin, FAImport);
cout << FAImport;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this problem exists, but it looks like there is a character limit of around 1000 for Xcode...

I switched over to Visual Studio on PC and it worked perfectly...